# Designing IDE in Qt; is there an already made compiler package I could use?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, ide, project

I am designing a simple IDE just as a side project.

I don't want to design a compiler for something that is just a side project that I will only be working on ever once in awhile.

So, is there some sort of pre-made, open source package I could use and link with my IDE?

Right now all I care about compiling is c and c++ but I want to add support for other languages (Java, C#, Perl, etc...) at some point, if I'm still working on the project.

Thanks.  Again, just to clarify, I am looking for a c/c++ compiler(compilers for other languages would also help) to link with my Qt made IDE project to compile the code written in my application.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, almost all IDEs do not contain their compilers, they call it as an external function.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Not looking on how to build my own.  Looking for a pre-built one and how to link it with my application.  I'm sure I can use the gcc compiler somehow, but I have to idea how to "call it" and use it to build code that is written in my application.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call command line GCC and capture output (stdout) to display in your application window.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a matter of invoking the desired compiler as an external process. You will need to pass the correct command line arguments, and presumably capture the output of the compiler and display it to the user in the GUI.

Since you are using Qt, I would suggest looking at [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html). QProcess provides a simple and platform-neutral way of invoking a process and communicating with it.

Apart from that, all you need is a way of generating the correct command line arguments for each compiler you wish to integrate with your IDE.